# Are new rows in oracle table reflected immediately in view?

Tags: oracle, view

Can someone please explain whether an Oracle database view requires refresh when new rows are inserted to the base tables?
In which scenarios is this true or false?

Comment: Try it.  A view is a stored query, nothing more.  If the rows are visible to the query (based on things like the current session's transaction isolation level), they will be visible when querying a view.  You don't refresh a view.  There is a thing called a "materialized view" which is very different but that is a much less common type of object that you generally run in to when you're looking at a data warehouse type environment

Answer (score 1):

There is no refresh to do. New rows are viosible to others at the same exact point in time in the table and in the view. That point is not insertion of data, but comitting the transaction.

Comment: It should be pointed out that new uncommitted rows are visible immediately if the view is queried in the same session that inserted them.